# How to properly use ReflectionFunction in this case?

Tags: php

I would like to execute code via ReflectionFunction,but taking into account complex code to execute rather than just a simple 'phpinfo();'

I tried:

```
     $test = $_GET['k'];
     $myfunc = new ReflectionFunction($test);
     $outText = $myfunc->invoke();
```

This basic scenario works well, but if for example my input would be "system('whoami'), it would not be executed because of course that function does not exist: *Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Function system('ls')() does not exist*

So, I tried this:

```
$strings=explode(',',$test);
$myfunc = new ReflectionFunction($strings[0]);
$outText = $myfunc->invokeArgs(array($strings[1]));
```

If the input has a ",", the script would split the string creating an array.. so, the string "system, ls" would be executed.
But at the same time, this is not elegant and not even convenient.. especially for a large  code to execute as input ( example input: get_current_user(); getcwd(); system('ls'); and so on.. and especially if there are variables )
How can I fix that?

Comment: Do you have pre-defined list of possible functions? E.g. do you allow to execute `exec('rm -rf /')`? Your task description sounds like job for `eval` and not `ReflectionFunction`

Comment: @Justinas thanks for your reply! I don't have any pre-defined list, I can't have any! I know  eval would be more appropriate, this is just in case eval is disabled by third part stuff

Comment: What about `call_user_func`/`call_user_func_array`?

Comment: this seems like serious security issue, i would consider that as backdoor, anyway in case you don't wanna pass whole function name and its parameters the only way is to make a list but then you are limited only to the defined list. if you wanna avoid the ReflectionFunction there is a variable-variable concept not that it solves your "having everything passed as get params" issue

Comment: @Justinas interesting! can you please make an example of how it would fit my case on any php online editor? I'm trying to use it, but I don't find any difference about that problem

Comment: @Kazz do not worry, it is just a local lab enviroment to study php. Can you please provide an example of that?